# Passing constructor arguments to OutputCacheProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, ninject

I have implemented a custom OutputCacheProvider

`public class MongoDBCacheProvider : OutputCacheProvider, IDisposable { ... }`

The cacheprovider is registered like so:

```
<outputCache defaultProvider="MongoDBCacheProvider" enableOutputCache="true"  >
  <providers>
    <add name="MongoDBCacheProvider" type="Mynamespace.Core.Caching.MongoDBCacheProvider, Mynamespace.Core" />
  </providers>
</outputCache>
```

I need to pass some arguments to the constructor. I want to use Ninject to bind my cache provider.

```
this.Bind<System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheProvider>()
    .To<Core.Caching.MongoDBCacheProvider>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("databaseName", dbName);
```

More arguments have to be passed, but this is just an example. I'm sure simple solutions exist to somehow get that string there, but i would prefer to use Ninject like i use for all other classes.

This fails with the message: "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." The following binding doesn't work either.

```
this.Bind<Core.Caching.MongoDBCacheProvider>().ToSelf()
    .InSingletonScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("databaseName", dbName);
```

I have verified that the binding runs before the error occurs. ASP .NET somehow bypasses the ninject bindings.
There doesn't seem to be any way to plug in a factory for it either.

Does anybody know how i can pass constructor arguments to a derived OutputCacheProvider?

Thank you.

Comment: You 100% Ninject is being asked to do the creation (why not include a stacktrace)? Have you searched for info re how similar ASP.NET (thinking membership providers but only 90% sure the comparison is valid) objects are managed under control of a DI Container?

Comment: @Ruben I've verified that it's loaded simply by putting a breakpoint there, which is hit before the error is shown. I'm not given a stacktrace when the error occurs. I followed your suggestion and tried the same approach for a membershipProvider. This did work as expected. A key difference might be that in order to test the membership provider i had to add it as an argument to a controller whereas the cacheprovider is not passed as an argument anywhere. ASP .Net itself constructs and uses it completely out of view. Could this make a difference? Thanks.

Comment: Sure could make a diff. IIRC (Search @Remo Gloor's blog for more authorative info), the way the Membership provider stuff works is that the startup pulls in the provider and then does a `Kernel.Inject` against the ASP.NET-created object. If that's not it, then it creates it and hands it off. You need to suss out who's going to be able to create it. If the answer is "Only SAP.NET/the system", then all that can be done is to do a Kernel.Inject on the object to trigger Constructor Setter / Intialization method calls. Re call stacks, there is always one - sometimes, it's just fiddlier to get

Comment: On reflection it seems v likey that your message has nothing to do with Ninject - is the message the exact Ninject one? What is the exception type? If the `outputCache` element is going to create the object, it's going to create the object until someone else tells it othersise - remember, Ninject doesn't make `new` (or `Activator.CreateInstance` etc.) magically do anything different...

Comment: @Ruben thanks for helping. I'm sorry i hadn't made this more clear. The error does not originate from Ninject. [Here is an image of the error i get.](http://i.imgur.com/LOwvx.png). I cannot uncover any stacktrace here. Is the binding i used faulty? I'm only a novice using Ninject, but it does work for my membership provider and all other classes i bind with Ninject. If it is impossible to bind the cacheProvider in this way are there good alternatives? Right now i have defined a parameterless constructor and resolve my dependencies by getting them from a global static collecion, a bad way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to `Inject` into the object early in your web app life cycle by causing it to be injected during app startup.

NB you will have to use [Property Setter Injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns) in preference to Constructor Injection, as there is likely no way to get the Cache Provider Provider to give you control of the instance creation.

See [this blog post by @Remo Gloor](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2012/02/08/asp-net-provider-injection-with-ninject-3-0-0/)

Comment: I have tried your approach by creating a CacheProviderDependencyCollection and marking this with the inject attribute. Unfortunately this means the dependencycollection is now part of the public interface, is this a good practice? The injection takes place after the Initialize method is called, this means i have to make a second initialization method and check if my cacheprovider has actually been initialized (connect to db) in the add, set, get and remove methods of the cacheprovider. If you think this is the best solution available for this particular problem then i will accept your answer.

Comment: @error_404 Dont know enough about `OutputCacheProvider` to say (have never used and cant even guess what FW version it arrived with); depends what era it was designed. Obv a messy workaround like this is only a small step up from you getting an `IKernel`. The bottom line is that any solution involving constructor injection as you want (and should want - your desire is most legitimate) will require the underlying system to give you a way to control the creation.